# adding and subtracting columns in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle11g

I have table `Inventory`

```
"INVENTORY_CODE" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL ENABLE 
"ITEM_CODE"      VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL ENABLE 
"WAREHOUSE_CODE" VARCHAR2(20) 
"CON_TON"        NUMBER(38,5) 
"IN_Q_TON"       NUMBER(38,5) 
"OR_Q_TON"       NUMBER(38,5) 
"RES_TON"        NUMBER(38,5) 
"RET_TON"        NUMBER(38,5)  
"ST_INV"         NUMBER(38,5)
```

and another table `Inventory_warehouse`

```
"CODE" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL ENABLE 
"ITEM_CODE" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL ENABLE 
"QUANTITY_AV_TON" NUMBER(38,5) 
"QUANTITY_AV_REAM" NUMBER(38,5) 
"QUANTITY_AV_SHEET" NUMBER(38,5)
```

I want to make a trigger to calculate `QUANTITY_AV_TON`

as

```
QUANTITY_AV_TON = IN_Q_TON + RES_TON + RET_TON + ST_INV - CON_TON - OR_Q_TON
```

I created this trigger but it didn't work

```
create or replace trigger QUANTITY_TON
AFTER insert or update or delete on INVENTORY
for each row
begin
  UPDATE INVENTORY_WAREHOUSE
     SET QUANTITY_AV_TON =
         select (IN_Q_TON + RES_TON + RET_TON + ST_INV - CON_TON -OR_Q_TON)
         from inventory
         where INVENTORY.item_code = INVENTORY_WAREHOUSE.item_code;
end;
```

the values of `IN_Q_TON` , `RES_TON` , `RET_TON` , `ST_INV` , `CON_TON` ,`OR_Q_TON` are calculated from other tables using triggers

Comment: I would recommend using a fast refresh materialized view.

Comment: So, what did not work?

Comment: PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expressionCompilation failed , PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: Your subquery needs to be enclosed in parentheses, but you'll likely get a mutating table error if you try to query the table the trigger is against, and you'll have contention issues from simultaneous changes firing the trigger at the same time, which would cause your totals to be off (if it worked at all). Triggers are not a good solution for this. Why not use a view to calculate the totals on the fly, or a materialised view if the calculation is expensive?

Comment: will the materialized view calculate the values automatically or i will have to write a code to call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to perform the calculation from the context values of the row in the trigger that is being processed.  This is normally done by using the ":NEW" variable. I have edited the trigger, but cannot run it, so please try it out.  Please read the [Oracle Trigger Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER QUANTITY_TON
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
   ON INVENTORY
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   UPDATE INVENTORY_WAREHOUSE
      SET QUANTITY_AV_TON =   :new.IN_Q_TON
                            + :new.RES_TON
                            + :new.RET_TON
                            + :new.ST_INV
                            - :new.CON_TON
                            - :new.OR_Q_TON
   WHERE INVENTORY_WAREHOUSE.ITEM_CODE = :new.ITEM_CODE;

END;
```

Comment: You'd need separate calculations for insert, update and delete though, to take the :old values - which won't exist for insert, and will only exist for delete - into account?

Comment: True, I was only thinking about insert.